# Call C++ function after QML animation finishes

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I need to call a C++ class method with parameters from UI after animation of SwipeView ends.

main.ui

```
ApplicationWindow {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    anchors.fill: parent

    Page1 {
        id: page1
    }

    Page2{
        id: page2
    }
}

XOR {
    id: xor
    onXorEnded: {
        //swipeView.setCurrentIndex(0)
    }
    onQChanged: {
        page2.bar.value = xor.getq()
    }
}
```

}

Page1Form.ui.qml

```
Page1Form {



kpButton.onClicked: {
    kpDialog.visible = true
}

xorButton.onClicked: {
    swipeView.setCurrentIndex(1)
    xor.crypt(file_path.text, key_path.text, out_path.text)
}

fpButton.onClicked:{
    fpDialog.visible = true
}


FileDialog {
    id: fpDialog
    onAccepted: {
        file_path.text = fpDialog.fileUrl
    }
}

FileDialog {
    id: kpDialog
    onAccepted: {
        key_path.text = kpDialog.fileUrl
    }
}
}
```

It seems like in xorButton.onClicked xoring starting before animation of swipe view ends. How it works now: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nflUH.jpg)

Comment: SwipeView doesn't provide access to its animation nor a method to set your own animation, so there is no easy way to do it. That's typical for built in QML controls, and the reason I don't use any of them. You either settle for what it provides, or do your own control if you want functionality and flexibility.

Comment: Your problem is that your `xor.crypt` method is a synchronous one (it returns only after all the data is computed), you should make it asynchronous if you want your desired behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround you can bind your action to index changing:

```
xorButton.onClicked: {
    swipeView.setCurrentIndex(1)
}


SwipeView {
    id: swipeView
    onCurrentItemChanged: {
        if(currentIndex == 1)
            xor.crypt(file_path.text, key_path.text, out_path.text)
    }
}
```

But anyway, that fires not at end of animation.

As another workaround you can use `StackView`. It has more properties to control the animation. Another advantage of this control is that user cannot swipe it when you don't expect it. In your case an user just can swipe that. One more advantage is that page doesn't take memory when you don't need it.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0


Window {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 800
    StackView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: page1
        onBusyChanged: {
            if(!busy && currentItem.objectName == "page2")
                currentItem.run();
        }
    }
    Component {
        id: page1
        Rectangle {
            color: "green"
            objectName: "page1"
            Button {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "swipe me"
                onClicked:
                    view.push(page2)
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: page2
        Rectangle {
            color: "yellow"
            objectName: "page2"
            function run() { sign.visible = true; }

            Rectangle {
                id: sign
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                width: 100
                height: 100
                radius: 50
                color: "red"
                visible: false
            }
        }
    }

}
```